# Ruby on Rails: Javascript Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My project's homepage displays system-wide data for the current month. The user may choose start and end dates that replace the view with system-wide data in the date range.

There is also a list below the system-wide data of specific services. If a service is clicked, it will replace the system-wide data with the data of the service which was clicked. The date range will also persist, so it will display the service data according to the date range.

For example, let's say I click on a service, the jquery function will display a partial for the service. Now, I want to change the date range, which should refresh the partial so that it will display the service data for the change in dates. But right now, if I choose to submit the start and end dates, it goes back to the system-wide data. How do I get it so that it stays on the specific service rather than going back?

This is my submit button, which has an id of 'submit_range' which corresponds to a jquery function:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id='submit_range'>Submit Range</a></div>
```

It calls a partial called '_submit_range.html.erb' which displays the system-wide data. 
The partial that displays the data for each specific service is in a partial called '_specific_service.html.erb'. Let me know if you need more code info!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider creating one form that includes both the service selection and the date-range specification.  When the user clicks "Submit Range" then the server will get both the desired service and the date range.

It's possible that, given your desired interaction, the service name may be a hidden field in the form that you fill in when the user "clicks on a service" (use one of the jQuery callbacks to put the name of the service into the hidden field when the ajax call is kicked off).